# Dates, Strings and Nonsense

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

I had some disturbing mail through the door the other day. It was addressed to me from an anonymous person. I was about to throw it in the bin when I saw that it was addressed to Beastly Gerbil, not my real name so I realised it was a puzzle. It started off like this:

> Someone is in danger, and you need to warn them. I can't say directly who in case this is intercepted so I have hidden it as a puzzle. Work this out and warn the person.

On the back was this:

> 23<sup>rd</sup> July 4516 - CEDFCED - If you do in fool's rain down
>   23<sup>rd</sup> April 7615 - DDAGAAF -Your condition that now slows a lie
>   21<sup>st</sup> March 6547 - GBBGGGC - A ceiling is across it your ground
>   17<sup>th</sup> April 6235 - CEDBBCE -  Won't you find your shoes missing who
>   27<sup>th</sup> April 6531 - EBBEBGD - Issue shallow wall whilst a about stop
>   23<sup>rd</sup> June 5417 - AACFCFA - Your wall shadows knows you'll from my
>   26<sup>th</sup> May 1734 - FFAGFDE - Is walking boots filling know suppose newts

**Who do I warn?**

Hint:

> @Levieux is on the final step. Now you just need to look at the [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography) tag. You are looking for a type of relative.

Comment: Is the 6th supposed to be missing a string, or was that a mistake?

Comment: no problem :P now to figure the puzzle out...

Comment: through it in the bin -> throw?

Comment: Your real name *isn't* Beastly Gerbil?!

Comment: @Deusovi I know. Surprising isn't it? :P

Comment: The real name is Bristly Beagle, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should warn your

> COUSIN

What got me started was this:

> All lines can be split up in three parts, as the title suggests: dates, strings and "nonsense".
>  All dates contain the numbers 1-7 when written out, except 25-4-7615, but this might be a typo and should then (probably) become 23-4-7615.
>  Next are the strings, they all consist of 7 characters. They also all contain only letter from A-G.
>  Last part is the "nonsense". Every line of this nonsense is exactly seven words long.

Putting this together:

> Most likely the numbers in the dates, together with the letters in the strings, tell us how to construct meaningful sentences out of the "nonsense".
>  The date numbers and their corresponding letters all form unique combinations, i.e. A-G are combined with 1-7 all exactly once.
>
>  We have:
>  **2C-3E-7D-4F-5C-1E-6D**
>  **2D-3F-4A-7G-6A-1A-5D**
>  **2G-1B-3B-6G-5G-4G-7C**
>  **1C-7E-4D-6B-2B-3C-5E**
>  **2E-7B-4B-6E-5B-3G-1D**
>  **2A-3A-6C-5F-4C-1F-7A**
>  **2F-6F-5A-1G-7F-3D-4E**
>
>   If you arrange the nonsense lines in a grid, like this:
>  [image: Option 1]
>  Or like this:
>  [image: Option 2]
>
>  Taking the indicated cells might be the solution, although I can't find anything meaningful in it yet..
>  I also tried sorting the lines by date (day and month) and by year and then applying the same logic, but this also leads to gibberish.
>
>  It looks like the beginning of each line is already (partially) correct, e.g. *If you do*, *A ceiling is*, *Won't you find* might well be the first word of meaningful sentences, so maybe we don't need to rearrange all the words quite as much...
>
>  Thanks to Piotr Pytlik:
>  If we now order all pieces (1A-1B-1C-...-1G-2A-2B-...-7G) we get:  
>  **A ceiling won't stop rain from filling
>
> your shoes, if your issue is a wall is missing.
>
> Suppose you lie about that wall,
>
> you'll find newts in your boots, a fool's condition.
>
> Who knows, it slows your shadows down,
>
> whilst walking across my shallow ground.
>
> Do you know now?**
>
>  Now to figure whom this is about.
>
>  Thanks to OP's hint, I found:
>  All letters preceding occurrences of the letter '*e*' spell out the word **COUSIN**.
>  A **C**eiling won't stop rain from filling
> your sh**O**es, if your iss**U**e is a wall is missing.
> Suppo**S**e you l**I**e about that wall,
> you'll find **N**ewts in your boots, a fool's condition.
> Who knows, it slows your shadows down,
> whilst walking across my shallow ground.
> Do you know now?

Comment: Think you mean I-1 and W-7

Comment: Good start, thanks for pointing out errors. I'm on mobile and copying from a picture so I can't check but think I fixed them correctly except for the day which I don't know, but think is right now

Comment: @DeepPurple: you're right! But anyway, it's changed now.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: I believe you've still got the date wrong. This way you'd have 3D and 5F twice and no 5D and 3F. Should be 23rd April 7615.

Comment: You are doing really well by the way. Think of how to arrange things

Comment: Hint: You have the right bits. You just haven't assigned them properly

Comment: @Levieux 7 words in each row, 7 letters, 7 numbers, i think you should put the first word of a row, into the grid which corresponds to the number + letter. For example ( "IF" into C2 ) and so on, for each word

Comment: Hey, my method so far gave "A ceiling wont stop rain filling your shoes..." - can't do more currently.

Comment: @PiotrPytlik: Thanks a lot, will edit that in

Comment: So close! The words condition and lie are mixed up, (from the dodgy date) but apart from that you are nearly there

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil There's still two 3Ds, no 3F, no 5D, two 5F.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: So I guess it should be 23rd April 7615 - DDAGAAF, then? I swapped the words "condition" and "lie", is it correct like that?

Comment: @Levieux Just for a little laugh, I really like your line "so maybe we don't need to rearrange all the words quite as much..." ;)

Comment: @Levieux probably. I can check when I'm home. Hint for the next step: this is were the steganography comes in

Comment: Or given the curious formatting and punctuation I wouldn't rule out a null cipher if we're hunting for a relative in this

Comment: Hint 2: Look at Rand's highest voted post and its answer

Comment: Well done you got it

Answer (score 0):

Partial
23rd July 4516 - CEDFCID - If you do in fool's rain down

> 23 7 4516 (7 numbers) - CEDFCID(7 letters) - If you do in fool's rain down(7 words)

25th April 7615 - DFAGAAD -Your condition that now slows a lie

> 25 4 7615 - DFAGAAD -Your condition that now slows a lie

21st March 6547 - GBBGGGC - A ceiling is across it your ground

> 21 3 6547 - GBBGGGC - A ceiling is across it your ground

17th April 6235 - CWDBBCE - Won't you find your shoes missing who

> 17 4 6235 - CWDBBCE - Won't you find your shoes missing who

27th April 6531 - EBBEBGD - Issue shallow wall whilst a about stop

> 27 4 6531 - EBBEBGD - Issue shallow wall whilst a about stop

23rd June 5417 - AACFCFA - Your wall shadows knows you'll from my

> 23 6 5417 - AACFCFA - Your wall shadows knows you'll from my

26th May 1734 - FFAGFDE - Is walking boots filling know suppose newts

> 26 5 1734 - FFAGFDE - Is walking boots filling know suppose newts

Comment: Ah, you're having the same idea I see :P

Comment: @Levieux yeah. just drop the 0 for the months. then the numbers probably tell you the correct order to place the 7 words or letter or something.